# French and Polish characters in one R-Markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, translation, multilingual, bookdown

I'm writing a book with translations of 100 Dutch songs to Polish. I'm proudly using R-Markdown and Bookdown on Win10 and really love it! All my needs/ideas are met/realized but one: French (some Dutch words are borrowed from French) and Polish characters in one document. Here are my MWE:

With French locale Polish characters are not displayed properly in R:

```
# French locale
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "French")
string <- c("Voyez le brick géant que j'examine près du grand wharf","\n", "Zażółć gęślą jaźń")
cat(string)
> Voyez le brick géant que j'examine près du grand wharf 
> Zazólc gesla jazn
```

With Polish locale French characters are not displayed properly in R:

```
# Polish locale
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Polish")
string <- c("Voyez le brick géant que j'examine près du grand wharf","\n", "Zażółć gęślą jaźń")
cat(string)
> Voyez le brick géant que j'examine pres du grand wharf 
> Zażółć gęślą jaźń
```

What I would love to see is:

```
> Voyez le brick géant que j'examine près du grand wharf 
> Zażółć gęślą jaźń
```

If I set locale X at the beginning of my R-markdown then html, pdf and epub looks perfects with regard to characters used in this locale, characters from the second locale are displayed in "basic" latin alphabet.
Is there any other method than "manual gsub" in the output files (html and tex)?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! 
For all special character outside Polish locale I'm using:
1. Latex Escaped Codes for References,
2. HTML Entities Codes for the rest.
Looks great now!